# How to export data from C to MATLAB (on different machines)

Tags: c, linux, matlab

I am generating long double float data in a C program on a Linux cluster. I need to export the data to Matlab, which is not installed on the cluster.

What is the best way? My advisor says to export using `printf` statements. I assume he means sending the data to a comma separated file (and `fprintf`). But it seems to me like that could be slow and use too much memory and we may lose a lot of precision.

I've found [this web page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/programming-interfaces-for-c-c-fortran-com.html) for reading and writing .MAT files, but I don't really understand the page, or [the example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/creating-a-mat-file-in-c.html), which I copied to my cluster, but cannot compile (because it's missing libraries which, obviously, come from MATLAB.

*What is the best, or easiest, or fastest way to export data from Linux/C to Windows/MATLAB? How do I get started with that method?* Be advised when you answer that I am pretty new to C and will likely need help figuring out how to obtain, install, configure, and link any libraries. But once that's done, I think I'm pretty good at learning to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think you would you lose precision? The only drawback with CSVs is that ASCII files require much more storage than binary files, but in this day and age where you get terabytes of storage for the price of a good haircut, that hardly seems like a problem.

It will only be noticeably slower if you're writing gigabytes upon gigabytes, but normally calculations take so much longer that the difference between ASCII and binary is completely negligible (and if the calculations *don't* take so long: why do you need a cluster then?)

In any case, I'd go for ASCII -- how to write and read some binary blob needs to be documented in two places, it's easier to create bugs in both the writing end and the reading end, it's harder to solve them since no human can read the file, etc. Also, MAT file formats may change in the next Matlab release (as they have in the past).

With ASCII, you have none of these problems, the only drawback I can think of is that you have to write a small cluster-specific file reader in Matlab (which is still a lot less work than working out all the bugs and maintaining a MAT file writer).

Anyway, there's tons of tools available in Matlab for ASCII: `textread`, `dlmread`, `importdata`, to name a few. On the C-end, indeed just use `fprintf` (documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/)).

Comment: +1: I concur with Rudy.  This will be the easiest solution for a newbie, and the newbie will have a solution faster (I make no guess about whether or not it will deliver a faster solution).  Whether or not it is the best way depends on one's point of view.

Comment: @High Performance Mark, atRody (they won't let me put two "@"): Feel I might lose precision because I can't seem to find the format string `width.precision` values for printing "all available precision". If I don't specify numbers in format string (e.g, "`%g`, `%f`, or `%e`), it seems to have a default cutoff. But apparently you print binary the same way. I will figure out what those numbers are. Feel it would be slower because too many times I've asked some program or other to read a large text file, and the program never comes back (that is, it hangs). Not terribly scientific, I admit.

Comment: Text import was quick enough. Matlab doesn't have as much precision as the C output, so saving precision was not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I once had this problem as well (well, kind of...) and used a simple binary format to do the job.

If your data format is static, that means if it will never change, you can restrict yourself to exactly what you need and hard-code the exact format in your loading program. If you want to stay flexible to add and remove columns, however, you should define a kind of header to add information about the data format and evaluate that on reading.

The trick for simple importing of data is the following:

- Let the MATLAB program know how longs your data records are and how they are composed.
- Read the data with

  ```
  rest = fread(fid, 'uchar=>uint8', 'b').';
  ```

  in order to have a row vector of `uint8`s.
- Reshape the data with

  ```
  rest = reshape(rest, recordlength, []).';
  ```

  in order to get your data in `recordlength` columns and as many rows as you need.
- For each data column, combine the relevant `uint8` rows into a "sub-matrix", using a combination of `reshape`, `typecast`, `swapbytes` to group your data appropriately and convert them into the wanted format.

  The most important thing here is the [`typecast()` function](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html), which accepts the "byte-wise" data as 1st and the wanted data type as 2nd parameter. There is a wide range of accepted data types, such as `intXX`, `uintXX` (with `XX` one of `8`, `16`, `32` and (AFAIK) `64`) as well as `float` and `double`.

  For example, `typecast([1, 1], 'uint16')` gives you `257`, while `typecast([0, 0, 96, 64], 'float')` gives you `3.5`.

Once you do so, you can improve the reading speed - compared with a text file - by factor 20 or so. (At least, this was the case in the application I wrote this for: there were about 10 different measure values every 10 ms, one measurement could be of several minutes or even hours and I wanted to read in such a file as fast as possible. So I recoded the stuff from text to binary and gained about factor 20, or maybe 15 - don't know exactly. But it was a lot...)

Comment: Can you clarify "if you data format is static" and that whole paragraph. I'm fairly new to C and just feeling my way around. Some details I (shouldn't have) left out: The data is generated over time and I want to write it out for each loop. The data is in a structure declared as `realtype z[2*N] = {0};`, and `realtype` is a `long double`. Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff This means: If you know beforehand what data you'll have and that rarely or never changes, you can hard-code the reading in your MATLAB applicaton. But if you want to stay flexible and later add/remove/change columns and/or their types, you have to code the alternatives into your file. As far as I can tell, you have one value per time and nothing else, and this will stay this way "forever"? Then you won't have to worry about reader-side detemining of the data format.

Comment: @Jeff One problem could be the fact that you have a `long double`, which has no equivalent in MATLAB according to my knowledge. (Am I right here?) So you'll have to recode to `double` on writing.

Answer (score 0):

I would save the workspace as a .MAT file, as you said. Then you have whatever values are contained in all the present variables saved as a workspace at that moment. However, if you are reading arrays (your data) that are gigabytes of long, then probably you read them chunk by chunk (due to RAM restrictions maybe?) and saving the workspace in that case might not help you.

I would never printf anything for transporting. In my work (on long time asymptotics, so I have huge outputs), I save everything as binary files using fwrite. Converting to text is slow and expensive, as far as I know.

I hope this helps a little bit!

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear. The data starts in C (on Linux) and needs to be moved to MATLAB (on Windows). So I think your advice is reversed.

Comment: Ok, how large is your data, for example?

Comment: It's going to be very large. We are going to do multiple runs. But one run could be, say, 16 data points across for long time periods, with data points exported every second. In other words, many rows by 16 columns of long float. Does that make sense? And help?

Comment: Then I would try doing this. At each iteration (second) dump the data as binary file (I believe this is the fastest and cheapest - 'fwrite'). After each T iterations, close the file. Another script should be called here and ship this file to other cluster where matlab is located. Meanwhile, your iteration should keep dumping the data in a new bin file. On the Matlab side, it will be easy to read them file by file, each file contains the data of T seconds/iterations. You can use any of the parallel programming tools to run these two modules. Choose an optimal size of T. This helps?

Comment: OK. I have to go read about `fwrite`. I was considering dumping the data and separating it by time. That is, instead of every T iterations, I would make a new file, say, every T hours. Is it better to do it by iterations?

Comment: You said you would dump the data every second, right? Keep doing it for T time units (seconds or whatever... can be several hours long). Experiment and compare the time it takes to ship the data saved for T time units vs the time it takes to do the computation for T time units. Then, choose a T value (like how many seconds you will store in each file). This way, while you are computing for the next T time units (seconds) you can shipped the previously computed and saved data simultaneously. This works like a pipeline and saves time, I believe. Once T is chosen, close the file after every T.

Comment: Yes, do not do it after you run the entire simulation. If you choose T accordingly: Suppose each computation for T seconds has real time N ~ shipping time. The way I wrote above, the total simulation and shipment takes N + 1 real time (as you do simultaneously). If you do it afterwards, it will take longer than than this. (I gotta leave now, sorry!)   Good luck!